# mongo db add field from other existing field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a new field to my documents using the value from another field and it's not working, it's creating an empty array:

```
db.getCollection('tripcollection').updateMany({}, [{ $set: { timestamp: '$transactions.0.timestamp' }}])
```

However, if I do it by using a field that is not an array, it works:

```
db.getCollection('tripcollection').updateMany({}, [{ $set: { timestamp: '$id' }}])
```

What is the correct way to do it by accessing an element of an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this once. can you sepecify also from where are you getting $transactions getting from.

```
db.getCollection('tripcollection').updateMany({}, [{ $set: { timestamp: '$transactions.0.timestamp' }}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself:

```
db.getCollection('tripcollection').find().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.getCollection('tripcollection').update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    timestamp: elem.transactions[0].timestamp
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```